# Smarty test fails in if-then-else

Tags: smarty, civicontact

I have an Email greeting containing a Smarty if-then-else expression:

```
{capture assign=language}{contact.preferred_language}{/capture}{if $language == 'fr_FR'}Bonjour{elif $language == 'nl_NL'}Hallo{else}Hello (should be in '{$language}'){/if}
```

When the preferred language of the contact is `nl_NL`, I expect the expression above would output

```
Hallo
```

but I get

```
Hello (should be in 'nl_NL')
```

This shows that Smarty is activated and the variable `$language` is correctly assigned, but the test is failing.

I would like to know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `{elif}` in smarty. Use `{elseif}`.

Comment: Gosh! Thank you.